Replacing NaN values in my data_df["country_name"] column
I have my original data frame = data_df which has 427 missing countries in the column data_df["country_name"] and the cities column data_df["city_name"] all  rows have a city name except 1 row. I have another data frame that has the missing country and city  names of about 261 rows. I would like to replace NaN values for the country_name in my original data set which are available in my new dataframe(261 rows). How can i achieve this.
I tried using indexing and my for loop  if the city_name is equal to city and replace the Nan value if its a match, instead i got more rows appended to my dataframe.
for city_index, city_name in enumerate(nan_rows["city_name"]):
    country =  nan_rows.iloc[city_index]["country_name"]
    print(f"City index is {city_index} and City name is {city_name} and county is {country}")
    for city in new_country_missing_df["city_name"]:
        if city ==  city_name:
            nan_rows.loc[city_index, "country_name"] = country

example of my dataframe:
nan_rows dataframe:
      country_name           city_name
535            NaN           Granville 
654            NaN  Kingston Upon Hull
787            NaN       New Waterford 
801            NaN           Kingstown 

new_country_missing_df dataframe:
              city_name                           country
0             Granville                            France
1    Kingston Upon Hull                    United Kingdom
2         New Waterford                            Canada
3             Kingstown  Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
4              Nanakuli                     United States


you need to create on the side clean mapping table - be it pandas DataFrame, or dict, then you either join or map to get right country. The mapping should provide single value for each city. The big issue is - this is a problem that is only the problem BECAUSE of your dataframe i.e. we don't know if NaN is really the only outlier or e.g. you have "France" and "france"...

The NaN(not a number) is on my column data_df["country_name"]  i generated a new frame by filtering the cities missing_cities  = data_df[data_df["country_name"].isna()] got a table after prompting chatgp, converted the excel document to csv file and load it up new_country_missing_df. I hope this answers the question. Dataset i got from kaggle

You can use map method:
nan_rows["country_name"] = nan_rows["city_name"].map(
    new_country_missing_df.set_index("city_name").country_name
)

in fact, you even don't need nan_rows dataframe, you can just apply it directly:
data_df.loc[data_df.country_name.isna(), "country_name"] = data_df.loc[
    data_df.country_name.isna(), "city_name"
].map(
    new_country_missing_df.set_index("city_name").country_name
)

